# Keep a record of all deletes with a trigger, including rollbacks

Tags: oracle, triggers, commit, rollback

Let's say I have 2 tables, `EMPLOYEE` and `EMP_BAK`. I need to create a backup table for all the data that deleted from employee, even these that are rolled back

My trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER emp_del_bak_trg
before delete ON employee 
FOR EACH row 
DECLARE 
oldname department.department_name%type;
newname department.department_name%type;
BEGIN
INSERT INTO emp_bak 
VALUES (:OLD.employee_id, :OLD.employee_name, :OLD.job
       ,:OLD.hire_date,:OLD.department_id, sysdate);
--commit;
end;
```

Now, if I rollback then the data will be deleted; if I uncomment out `commit`, I'll get an error on deleting. The idea is to keep the record plus keep track of the system updates.

Any ideas how to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### There is almost never a good reason to commit inside a trigger.

Now, that's out of the way your situation seems to be extra special, you need to track it, even if the transaction is rolled back. This is a fairly unusual requirement, but I'm going to assume you have a *very* good reason for doing this.

If you really, really, want to do this you need to use an [autonomous transaction](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/transact.htm#CNCPT417), this enables an independent transaction to be committed within another. As a trigger is a PL/SQL block, you can do this in a trigger.

The Oracle documentation has a separate section [dealing with autonomous transactions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#CIHEHGED) in triggers, with plenty of examples for you. Wherever you need to use one the syntax is as follows, this is always placed in the DECLARE block:

```
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
```

Your trigger, therefore, would look as follows:

```
create or replace trigger emp_del_bak_trg
   before delete on employee 
   for each row 
declare 
   PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
begin

   insert into emp_bak 
   values ( :old.employee_id, :old.employee_name, :old.job
          , :old.hire_date, :old.department_id, sysdate);
   commit;

end;
/
```

As a little note I always case this differently so it's obvious you're doing something that you shouldn't be. Autonomous transactions are dangerous and should be used with extreme care.